# с++ Аргумент типа "const wchar_t"* несовместим с параметром типа "wchar_t"

Tags: c++, wchar-t

не могу вызвать "GetProcessByExeName"

```
DWORD GetProcessByExeName(wchar_t* ExeName)
{
PROCESSENTRY32W pe32;
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);

HANDLE hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error CreateToolhelp32Snapshot", L"error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}

if (Process32FirstW(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
{
    do
    {
        if (_wcsicmp(pe32.szExeFile, ExeName) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
            return pe32.th32ProcessID;
        }
    } while (Process32NextW(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
}

CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
return 0;
```

}

Вызывая так `GetProcessByExeName(L"chrome.exe");` пишет -> Аргумент типа "const wchar_t"* несовместим с параметром типа "wchar_t"

Comment: Используйте везде `std::string`

Comment: я понимаю, если бы рекомендовать `std::wstring` (там же `wchar_t`), Но в любом случае совет скорее вреден, чем полезен.

Comment: Вы ошиблись, там должно было быть написано: `Аргумент типа const wchar_t * несовместим с параметром типа wchar_t *`. А всё потому, что передача указателя на константу в качестве обычного указателя, естественно, недопускается, потому что это нарушает логику.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение 1:
записать значение в переменную, а потом вызвать функцию

```
    wchar_t* str = new wchar_t[] {L"chrome.exe"};
    GetProcessByExeName(str);
```

Решение 2: добавить const в прототипе функций, что скажет компилятору: "Эта функция не меняет значения по передаваемому указателю"

```
DWORD GetProcessByExeName(const wchar_t* ExeName)
{
PROCESSENTRY32W pe32;
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);

HANDLE hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error CreateToolhelp32Snapshot", L"error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}

if (Process32FirstW(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
{
    do
    {
        if (_wcsicmp(pe32.szExeFile, ExeName) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
            return pe32.th32ProcessID;
        }
    } while (Process32NextW(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
}

CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
return 0;
}
```

Вызывать в таком случае, как вы хотели раньше

Answer (score -1):

```
DWORD GetProcessByExeName(const wchar_t* ExeName)
{
PROCESSENTRY32W pe32;
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);

HANDLE hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Error CreateToolhelp32Snapshot", L"error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}

if (Process32FirstW(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
{
    do
    {
        if (_wcsicmp(pe32.szExeFile, ExeName) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
            return pe32.th32ProcessID;
        }
    } while (Process32NextW(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
}

CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это решение или дополнение к вопросу?

Comment: это похоже на решение. добавление `const` к аргументу функции решает проблемы.